# Better brake pads

Tags: brakes

I am frequently having to adjust my brakes because of brake pad wear.

I do not have to do major braking.

Are there other brake pads that wear longer that do not cost big bucks?

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 2):

Braking performance is a tradeoff between hardness and grippiness.

A brake pad that stops you really well tend to be softer than pads which last a long time.

You can somewhat compromise by using a longer brake pad, if your bike allows this - a longer pad isn't normally much more expensive than a shorter one, but the additional material means it lasts longer.

---

Another way to help your rim brake pads last longer is to clean the rims, especially if you ride in the dirt and/or rain and/or sand, or your bike tends to get quite dusty as you ride.   The dirt and grit acts as a grinding paste between the pad and rim, wearing away both while decreasing your braking effectiveness.

If you have V brakes or Cantilevers, they're generally easy to flip open and wash.  Take the chance to pick out any objects embedded in the pad.  Metal is common, and Glass/wood are not unknown.  This extends the life of your rim too.

For caliper brakes, its a bit harder.  You can get brake pad shoes which accept replaceable pads, which can be slid out after undoing one small retaining screw.

We don't generally recommend specific brands, but price is a good reflection on quality.  Super expensive pads will wear very quickly, middle-price ones are a nice balance, and cheap pads last forever (as does your braking phase!)

Personally I like Salmon-coloured pads that are shaped to suit my brake.

The notes above are specific to rim brakes.

Comment: My expensive brake pads (SwissStop Flash Pro BXP, about 20€ per pair) last a very long time. On the road bike I have more than 10Mm on them and are still going strong.

Comment: @Michael good point - road bike brake pads also last longer than bikes used off-road.  Swiss stop is uncommon here, but I'd rank them up there with Kool Stop for overall excellence.

Comment: @Micheal what’s 10Mm I’m not familiar with that metric ? Obviously being in the UK I understand Km / M / Meters but never heard Mm before

Comment: @DanK some people use megametres.

Comment: Cheap pads can wear quickly or slowly, but either way lack stopping power in the wet. I like dual compound for rim brakes, kool-stop by choice, but I've had some from XLC (I think that's what they're called) that did well. They were the first ones I used that were dual compound and also longer the the stock pads

Comment: Great attempt to write around the fact that some brake pads just are over all better than others and hardness isn't the only variable. The price/hardness correlation also isn't exactly true. And yes, those salmon-colored pads work very well for most, but it's because of the rubber compound that's specific to two brands, not the color.